# `missing-syscalls' error during kernel compilation

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

These are the steps I am doing to compile the linux source on my machine : 
1. Copy the config file from /boot to /usr/src/kernels/2.6.29.4-167.fc11.i586/ directory 
2. make oldconfig 
3. make

Step 3 fails with the following error : 
make[1]: *** No rule to make target `missing-syscalls'.  Stop.

Compiling on a x86 box. 
Any suggestions ? 
Please feel free to close this question if it does not belong here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not been able to answer why this error happens : 
Step 3 fails with the following error : make[1]: *** No rule to make target `missing-syscalls'. Stop.

But I was able to compile the vanilla version fine, without the above error. 
I asked the same question on serverfault as well, which has a more detailed explanation of the steps taken : https://serverfault.com/questions/61354/missing-syscalls-error-during-kernel-compilation

Answer (score 2):

As archaic as it may sound it appears that currently in order to get kernel source on a system you have to manually select the source you want.  One supposes that people don't build kernels as often as they used to and of course you may want to develop a kernel that does not match the version that you are running..

So for example I wanted to install VBox on my CentOS 6.2 box and while most kernel modules can be compiled without complete sources this update failed.

So I found this wiki page:
http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/I_need_the_Kernel_Source

It doesn't list 6.2 and the naming conventions have changed on the final directory name so to get the 6.2 kernel source you go to http://vault.centos.org/6.2/updates/Source/ and select the version you want.  If you want source for a different version go to http://vault.centos.org/ and navigate from there.

The docs recommend against doing an rpm-build on the kernel sources.

Answer (score 0):

Make a new config file. Maybe the old one isn't working?

Comment: Tried that as well. See the same error with the new config file.

Answer (score 0):

since kernel **3.x.x** this message appears if trying to build external modules having only single Makefile prepared.

Instead, according to [this manual](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/kbuild/modules.txt),

splitting into **Kbuild** (where all the source files are listed, example):

`obj-m := module_source.c`

and simple **Makefile** (having only default make directive, example):

`default:
    $(MAKE) -C $(KDIR) M=$$PWD`

will solve the problem.

just in case, external module build directive would be following:

`make -C <kernel source path> -M=<module source folder>`

example: `make -C . -M=extra/`